# Reorder subject number from low to high in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with structure like this. Can I re-order the row by subject number as subject 1, subject 2, subject 3, with number from low to high?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could change the order with `mixedorder` from `gtools`

```
library(data.table)
library(gtools)
dt2 <- dt1[mixedorder(subject)]
```